# Selection of container to insert the multiple db recored

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl, containers

In my current task , I need to read the read the approximately 10,000 records (student data) from database and need to store the same in container. Now I need to select container to store all this records in order to generate the report. Report generation option Is vendor specific as one vendor wants to dump the all the records without sorting and other vendor wants to generate the report based on sorted name field. I have selected vector from my end as i don't require any kind of insertion in the middle and no searching effort is required for first option (report without sorting the fields) but for second option can anybody suggest me if vector would be suitable option for the same by introducing sorting based on name field.

below is the some useful pointers which I found  in scott meyers book (Effective STL) in item 23 . I believe based on below information for second option sorted vector needs to be used but still I want somebody to through some light on this before I come to any conclusion and start coding.

Item 23. Consider replacing associative containers with sorted vectors

"**The standard associative containers are typically implemented as balanced binary search trees. A balanced binary search tree is a data structure that is optimized for a mixed combination of insertions, erasures, and lookups. That is, it's designed for applications that do some insertions, then some lookups, then maybe some more inser-tions, then perhaps some erasures, then a few more lookups, then more insertions or erasures, then more lookups, etc. The key characteristic of this sequence of events is that the insertions, erasures, and lookups are all mixed up. In general, there's no way to predict what the next operation on the tree will be"

Comment: Just loop through the vector, only picking out the records that fit the condition? 10000 elements is not that much to loop over really. It can be made very simple (from your perspective) if you use e.g. [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the wanted elements to another vector (with the help of e.g. [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)).

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Meyers suggests `std::vector` is very good container for storing data and to manipulate it - with some exception - if the data is quite big - not only by number of elements but also element size matters.

You can reduce the size of data to manipulate by not manipulating the data itself - but by manipulating the indices to that data.

Assuming you have already vector read from file:

```
struct Element { .... };
std::vector<Element> data;
readData(someFile);
```

You can generate "natural order" of those records by creating such vector of indices (see [iota on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)):

```
using indices = std::vector<std::size_t>;
indices naturalOrder(data.size());
std::iota(naturalOrder.begin(), naturalOrder.end(), 0); // filled with 0,1,2,...
```

To print records using this indices - define such algorithm:

```
template <typename Container, typename Indices, typename Operation>
void for_erach(Container&& container, const Indices& indices, Operation&& op)
{
    for (auto i: indices) 
        op(container[i]);
} 

// print in natural order
for_each(data, naturalOrder, [] (auto const& e) { 
    std::cout << e << std::endl; 
});
```

To sort, just sort indices:

```
Indices sorterdByXOrder = naturalOrder;
auto lessX = [&data](auto i, auto j) { return data[i].x < data[j].x; };
std::sort(sorterdByXOrder.begin(), sorterdByXOrder.end(), lessX);
// print in sorted by x  order
std::cout << "Sorted by x:" << std::endl;
for_each(data, sorterdByXOrder , [] (auto const& e) { 
    std::cout << e << std::endl; 
});
```

To have only indices for e.g. element.y == 7 - do this:

```
Indices onlyY7Order;
auto yIs7 = [&data](auto i) { return data[i].y == 7; };
std::copy_if(naturalOrder.begin(), naturalOrder.end(),
          std::back_inserter(onlyY7Order),  yIs7);
```

IF you would have performance problem to read entire data to `std::vector` - you can try with `std::deque` - in some cases it could be faster. The rest of code I presented will not change - because `std::deque` and `std::vector` have very similar interfaces...